# Avoid overlapping x-axis labels with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am new to R, I tried searching for the answer in this community but could not find it. I created a plot for some data and my code is this:

```
q2<-ggplot(main_data, aes(x= Advertising, y= BrandRevenue)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size = BrandValue, color= Brand, label = Brand))

q2

q2 + scale_x_continuous(name = "Company Advertising in Billions of $", 
                        breaks =seq(0, 4.8, 0.1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Brand Revenue in Billions of $", 
                       breaks= seq(4, 10, 2))
```

And this is the visualization which i get:

[image]

As you can all see the values on x-axis are all cramped up and overlapping each other. The values I am using for company advertising on x-axis is from o to 4.8 with an interval of 0.1 between consecutive numbers, i.e. 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and continues till 4.8. So is there any way in ggplot that these values on x-axis look evenly spaced i.e. I want my values on x-axis to somewhat look like this:

[image]

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Basically, you just need to make your plot wider. But in order for us to help you with that, we need to know how you're saving your image. Are you saving it with the `ggsave()` function? Is this in an HTML document created by knitr?

Comment: (Or you could just choose more spacious breaks with `breaks = seq(0, 4.8, 0.25)` or something like that)

Comment: OR you could use minor breaks if you have to have a line every 0.1, but use major breaks to control the labels: `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4.8, 0.5), minor_breaks = seq(0, 4.8, 0.1))`

Comment: I am saving the image using "save as image" under Export.

Comment: Also I ran the following code : scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4.8, 0.5), minor_breaks = seq(0, 4.8, 0.1)), the overlapping thing was solved but the distance between points on x-axis shows 0.5, is there a way for the visualization to show a distance of 0.1 between points on x-axis without overlapping.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably just want to make the plot wider. I'd suggest using the `ggsave()` function ([help file](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggsave.html)), and specify the `width` until you get something you like.